# passing multiline string via .env file docker

Tags: docker

Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) in regards to `.env` file are lacking in detail.

In docker-compose.yml file I've:

```
LETSENCRYPT_HOST: |
      abc.domain.com,
      abe.domain.com,
      aba.domain.com
```

I'd like to move this to `.env` file, is this possible?

docs say

> Compose expects each line in an env file to be in VAR=VAL format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It boils down to the [`config/environment.py#env_vars_from_file()`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/dc88e540106e7f74d6d8fcb9cae52a8d56e1fb2b/compose/config/environment.py#L25-L39) function:

```py
def env_vars_from_file(filename):
    """
    Read in a line delimited file of environment variables.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        raise ConfigurationError("Couldn't find env file: %s" % filename)
    elif not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise ConfigurationError("%s is not a file." % (filename))
    env = {}
    for line in codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8'):
        line = line.strip()
        if line and not line.startswith('#'):
            k, v = split_env(line)
            env[k] = v
    return env
```

It should be easy to submit a PR asking for lines ending with '`\`' to be considered multiple lines.
But right now, it is not the case.